# Read CSV with two different delimiters

Tags: python, pandas

I have an [example file](http://pastebin.com/RPr59idq) of the type of file I am working with. 
Sometimes the delimiter is `|` and other times it's `*`.

The closest I have come to successfully reading this is:

```
data = pd.read_csv('filename', 
                   skiprows=244, sep=r'\|',
                   header=None,
                   names=['A','B','C','D','E'])
new = data['E']
df = new.str.split().apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x))
df = df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
```

But the problem with this is that I end up with `None` rows  where my delimiter was a `*`.

Is there a way to separate this file based on two different delimiters? I have thought about using a regular expression to match either `|` or `*` but

```
data = pd.read_csv('filename', 
                   skiprows=244, nrows=5, sep=r'(\| | \*)',
                   header=None,
                   names=['A','B','C','D'])
```

doesn't seem to work either. I am not the greatest at reg expressions though.

EDIT:
I have also tried using `sep=r'\s*'`, but seeing as how the `*`'s move around in the file, it makes it to where some rows are shifted, and therefore the columns do not align.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those asterisks everywhere are really problematic because, as you mention, sometimes they replace the `|` delimiter and other times they're in the middle of a field seemingly at random.

Luckily your file seems to be fixed width, which pandas [knows how to handle](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#files-with-fixed-width-columns) with `read_fwf` (fixed-width file).

Let's take a little subset of this nasty data file which shows both asterisk positions:

```
 |                   *                   |                   |  0.1108      0.0085 ( 1.883%)     0.1066 ( 0.504%)
 |                   |                   |                   |  0.1112      0.0001 (20.851%)     0.1066 ( 0.504%)
 |                   |                   |                   |  0.1116      0.0005 ( 7.536%)     0.1072 ( 0.502%)
 |                *  |                   |                   |  0.1120      0.0059 ( 2.266%)     0.1130 ( 0.488%)
 |                   |                   |                   |  0.1124      0.0001 (16.439%)     0.1131 ( 0.487%)
```

We can read this with some careful (but boring) counting of character positions:

```
In [9]: colspecs = [(64, 71), (76, 83), (85, 90), (97, 104), (106, 111)]

In [11]: pd.read_fwf('my_file.csv', colspecs=colspecs, header=None)
Out[11]: 
        0       1      2       3      4
0  0.1108  0.0085  1.883  0.1066  0.504
1  0.1112  0.0001  0.851  0.1066  0.504
2  0.1116  0.0005  7.536  0.1072  0.502
3  0.1120  0.0059  2.266  0.1130  0.488
4  0.1124  0.0001  6.439  0.1131  0.487
```

Comment: beautiful. I for some reason have never seen or used ```read_fwf```, perfect solution. Thanks!

Comment: On some of the files I am running this on, I get a StopIteration error. Any idea why?

Comment: Perhaps post this, along with some details as a new question. That way it will get more attention from our resident geniuses!

Comment: That was actually my bad. It was only happening on one file, and that is because that file was for some reason incomplete. Nothing wrong with your solution. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can go the old fashioned way, and build a list:

```
rows = []
for line in open('filename'):
    var1 = int(line[62:70])
    ....
    rows.append([var1, ...])

data = pd.DataFrame(data=rows, columns=['A','B','C','D'])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('C:/example_file.txt') as f:
    content = [x.strip('\n') for x in f.readlines()]
content.pop(0)
cleancontent = []
for index, item in enumerate(content):
    cleancontent.append(content[index][62:])
cleancontent
```

Then turn this into the dataframe.